# How to pass parameters in Maven

Tags: angular, maven, npm

In the code below, instead of '/myapp' I want to pass a parameter dynamically to which it should build the project dynamically, given the base href.

```
<!-- It will execute command "npm build" inside "/angular" directory to clean and create "/dist" directory--> 
<execution>  
     <id>npm build</id> 
     <goals> 
        <goal>npm</goal> 
     </goals> 
     <configuration> 
           <arguments> run build --base-href /myapp/ </arguments>         
     </configuration> 
  </execution>
```

---